# How to understand "Let F be any field. A Sequence in F is a function x, from the positive integers into F."

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble understanding these statements right here:

"Let F be any field. A Sequence in F is a function x, from the positive integers into F."

Here is what I know so far. My professor told me to just regard a field as the set of all real or complex numbers. I know that a sequence is a collection of objects, but if that is true, what is the difference between a sequence and a set? My professor also told me to just regard a set as simply: a collection of objects. Lastly, what does it mean to have positive integers into the field?

If anyone can help me break these sentences down, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: A set is like a basket where all the items are jumbled up with no order. A sequence is when the items are placed side by side in a row. A sequence therefore has a first element, a second element, etc., whereas in a set the items are mixed up pell-mell.

Comment: A field is a collection of objects that obey certain properties.  Essentially they say you can add, subtract, multiply, and divide with the properties we expect for those operations based on our experience with the reals.  The sequence/set question does not depend on the field structure at all.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot make sense of what you are saying, really. But a sequence $x$ is indeed a function $$\tag{1}x:\mathbb N\to F.$$
You say a sequence is "a collection of objects"; I would challenge you to define that notion properly.  The "good" way is $(1)$. You are used to write $x_n$ for the entries of $x$; you can think that it is just notation for $x(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is any set, then a sequence in $X$ is a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$, that is, a function whose domain is the natural numbers and whose codomain is $X$.

It's customary to suppress the function $f$ and simply write $x_n=f(n)$. For instance, if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(n)=(-1)^n$, then we would instead write $x_n=(-1)^n$.

The important distinction between a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and the set $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is that the sequence comes with an ordering, while a set is an unordered collection of elements.

Comment: As your answer implies, it is not important that $F$ is a field.  It works with any set.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: yes, good point. It's not entirely clear to me what the connection is to linear algebra.